# Showing Category and sub category when admin browse orders

Tags: php, laravel-4

When customer submit his order it is stored in database table `orders` in array. The array looks like:

```
{
    "15": // product_id
    {
        "title":"Test of title", // product_title
        "description":"Test of description", // product_description
        "quantity":1,
        "price":132 
    },
    "shipping": // selected shipping information
    {
        "title":"Normal Delivery" - $10.00",
        "price":10
    }
}
```

Then in my Order `Model` I have this

```
public function getOrderData($data) { 
    return json_decode($data); 
}
```

In the controller

```
public function orders() {

    $orders = Order::select('*')->paginate(10);
        return View::make('admin.orders', [
            'orders' => $orders
        ]);
}
```

On the view I've  made one foreach and displaying information for the order from this array like

```
@foreach($order->getOrderData($order->data) as $itemId => $item)     
    Title of product
    Description of product
    Price of product        
@endforeach
```

What I want to make is same view but in front of the `Title of product` to show also Category name and sub-category name, like

```
@foreach($order->getOrderData($order->data) as $itemId => $item) 

    Category 1 -> Sub_category 1 -> Title of product
    .... // other info
@endforeach
```

**Problem**: I don't have anything for `category` and `sub-category` in that array and in orders table at all. Tried to join tables Category and Sub-Category but they doesn't have columns in `order` table only in `product` table I store `category_id` and `sub_category_id`.

How can I show them?

Update 2: Changed `getOrderData` in Order Model like this

```
public function getOrderData($data) {

    $dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $arrayKeys = array_keys($dataArray);
    $arrayKeys = array_filter($arrayKeys, function($value) {
        return ($value !== 'shipping');
    });
    $productIds = implode(',', $arrayKeys);

    $products = 
        DB::table('products')
        ->join('category', 'products.product_id', '=', 'category.category_id')
        ->join('sub_category', 'products.sub_cat_id', '=', 'sub_category.sub_cat_id')
        ->whereIn('product_id',$productIds) ;



    foreach ($products as $item) {
        if(!in_array($item['product_id'], $arrayKeys)) continue;
        $dataArray[$item['product_id']]['category'] = $item['category']; // depending on the implementation $item may be array or an object! so this code may vary
        $dataArray[$item['product_id']]['subcategory'] = $item['subcategory'];
    }
    return (object) $dataArray;   
  //return json_decode(json_encode($dataArray));        
}
```

Got error:

> array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Update: This query in phpmyadmin is returning me all the information for product with id=9 + all information for category and sub-category

```
SELECT * 
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON p.category_id =1
LEFT JOIN sub_category AS sc ON p.sub_cat_id =1
WHERE p.product_id =9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you this solution:
After getting the result for the order from the table you can iterate over the order to get productIDs. Then do select query like this one:

```
SELECT fields FROM products AS p
JOIN categories AS c ON ...
JOIN sub_categories AS sc ON ...
WHERE p.id IN (productIDs)
```

And the code to get product ids is something like this:

```
public function getOrderData($data) {
    $dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $arrayKeys = array_keys($dataArray);
    $arrayKeys = array_filter($arrayKeys, function($value) {
        return ($value !== 'shipping');
    });
    $productIds = implode(',', $arrayKeys);

    // QUERY FOR selecting product categories, so when this query return results you can merge them with order data.
    $productsInfo = ....

    foreach ($productsInfo as $item) {
        if(!in_array($item['productId'], $arrayKeys)) continue;
        $dataArray[$item['product_id']]['category'] = $item['category_name']; // depending on the implementation $item may be array or an object! so this code may vary
        $dataArray[$item['product_id']]['subcategory'] = $item['sub_cat_name '];
    }

    // If products is array of objects use this code
    //foreach ($productsInfo as $item) {
    //    if(!in_array($item->productId, $arrayKeys)) continue;
    //    $dataArray[$item->product_id]['category'] = $item->category_name; // depending on the implementation $item may be array or an object! so this code may vary
    //    $dataArray[$item->product_id]['subcategory'] = $item->sub_cat_name ;
    //}
    return (object) $dataArray;
}
```

If `return (object) $dataArray;` doesn't give you the same response structure as in the response in your question then:

```
return json_decode(json_encode($dataArray)); // for example
```

If you add additional info about table structure I can give you better answer.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. The query is fine I can change whit my fields. What I don't understand how to make is `After getting the result for the order from the table you can iterate over the order to get productIDs` Can you give me an example?

Comment: I edited my answer and added the code you asked for.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with what I've tried and what error I've got. So I tried to implement your solution but so far got this error.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Just edited the answer... it`s little ugly having two json_decode but I don't know if it will be a problem for your implementation $data to be array, so that's why I added one more $dataArray :)

Comment: Now `'json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` this appear

Comment: Okay. Now the problem in the view and how to call in foreach because I've got `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`  here `@foreach($order->getOrderData($order->data) as $itemId => $item)`

Comment: Do you return any result in the end of  getOrderData? You should merge somehow products info data (`$products`) with order data (`$data`) and return it.

Comment: tried to array_merge them but $products isn't array. Any other solution?

Comment: Not direct array_merge. You can for example iterate over `$products` (in which you have product id corresponding to an element in orders data). So you can easily get info for the product and add it to the exact `$data` item related to the given product id.

This is just an example .... you have to modify it for your needs:
`foreach ($products as $item) {
        $data[$item['productId']]['productInfo'] = $item;
    }`

Comment: Sorry but what `['productInfo']` should be? what info.. from which table or.. i've got lost and have no idea.

Comment: And after the foreach what should I `return ...` and the foreach in the view.

Comment: Now this :`'Illegal string offset 'productId'`

Comment: Yes because it is not the correct implementation code. You should change it according to your returned result from the products query (see what are the fields returned from the query)

Comment: In my code it is productId but in the query is product_id.
Dump the result from the query and replace the necessary fields in the code.

Comment: Add dump of $products to get picture of the data.

Comment: Something bad happen - `'Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 58720256 bytes)'`

Comment: Ok, then can you give just the structure of the result returned from: `DB::table('products')
        ->join('cat.................`

Comment: What you mean by `structure of result`?

Comment: each product is has `product_id` and `category_id` for category in which is added and `sub_cat_id` for sub-category

Comment: I've updated my question with query which returning me correct result in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Got it to the point page load and display correct order data. How to show now category name?

Comment: I'm trying like this but seems not correct `$item['category']['category_name']` because I've got error `'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'`

Comment: Please add the column names for every table in the select query (category , products, sub_category)

Comment: I can't edit my question at the momment.. I don't know why but the query is same and here is the select of column names `SELECT product_id, category_name, sub_cat_name ....`

Comment: And in my view I access categories names like `$item['category_name']`, `$item['sub_cat_name']`?

Comment: No, you should be able to access them like you access product `title` in the view, but instead of `title` you would have `category` and `subcategory`

Comment: I've got `'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array'` here `if(!in_array($item['productId'], $arrayKeys)) continue;`

Comment: You didn't check my commented code from the last edit. Try it. Your $products is obviously array of objects.

Comment: `'Undefined property: stdClass::$productIds'` here `if(!in_array($item->productIds, $arrayKeys)) continue;`

Comment: Why it is showing that isn't defined? Isn't defined here `$productIds = implode(',', $arrayKeys);`?

Comment: $productIds and $item->productIds are different. For the in_array you should use $productIds

Comment: But now if I make it like `if(!in_array($productIds, $arrayKeys)) continue;` I've got `'Trying to get property of non-object` on the forech in my view -> here: `@foreach($order->getOrderData($order->data) as $itemId => $item)`

Comment: `if(!in_array($productIds, $arrayKeys)) continue;` is wrong ... use this `if(!in_array($item->productId, $arrayKeys)) continue;`
And instead of `return (object) $dataArray;`   use  `return json_decode(json_encode($dataArray));`

Comment: Again `'Undefined property: stdClass::$productId'` on this line `if(!in_array($item->productId, $arrayKeys)) continue;`

Comment: if(!in_array($item->product_id, $arrayKeys)) continue;

Comment: No got `'Undefined property: stdClass::$category` on the view where Im trying to show category name `$item->category`

Comment: Any idea how to access them now?

Comment: `var_dump($item)` I see that ['category'] and sub-category are there but can't access them?

Comment: Can you do var_dump($dataArray[$item->product_id]); right after $dataArray[$item->product_id]['subcategory'] = $item->subcategory;
    } and post the response

Comment: Yes, here is the var_dump: `array(7) { ["title"]=> string(22) "Test Product" ["description"]=> string(9) "Description" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["image"]=> string(16) "/img/noimage.png" ["price"]=> int(132) ["category"]=> string(15) "Test Category 1" ["sub_category"]=> string(10) "sub cat 01" }`

Comment: And how you return the result in the end of the function?

Comment: with this `return json_decode(json_encode($dataArray));`

Comment: Ok, so in the view you should be able to access them using

Comment: Using this `$item->category` ? Unfortunately I'm not  and I've got `'Undefined property: stdClass::$category`

Comment: Ok, so in the view you should be able to access them using $item->category and $item->sub_category and you can test if they are set and only if they are set they should be printed out: {{ isset($item->category) ? $item->category : '' }}

Comment: Wow.. Why with `isset` they're visible but without `isset` I've got this error even if they exist?

Comment: May be because of the last element which is "shipping" which doesn't have category and sub_category elements.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for wasting your time! Appreciated it!

Comment: I'm glad we finally get to solution of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

When you do `json_decode` it converts associative array to objects that's why you are getting this error when passing this decoded json data; So before using this decoded data `cast` it to `array`;

```
$data = (array) json_decode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked also like this. The problem now is how to return both result from query + $data to view..